# C++ My first template ever

Tags: c++, templates, ambiguity

Ok, which is the best to avoid ambiguity here?

```
template <class T>
inline void swap(T &a, T &b)
{
    T c; c = a; a = b; b = c;
}
/* blah blah blah (inside of a function:) */
for (itv = vals.begin(); itv != vals.end(); ++itv)
{
    if (at < (*itv)) { swap(at, (*itv)); }
    if (at % (*itv) == 0) atadd = false;
}
/* blah blah blah */
```

Calling with a swap doesn't work either, as it says cannot resolve whether it is "void swap(T &,T &)", "void std::swap(_Ty &,_Ty &)" or ...

Btw, itv is a vector<int>::iterator.

Thx.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is namespace `std` also contains `swap()` function and looks like you have `using namespace std;` somewhere earlier, so the compiler can't decide which `swap()` to use - yours from the global namespace or the one from namespace `std`.

You need to prepend the call with "`::`" to explicitly tell the compiler to use your `swap()` from the global namespace instead of from namespace `std`. Alternatively you could rename your `swap()` function or not use `using namespace std;`.

Comment: This brings us to why redefine `swap`, when it is already available in the standard.